# Java reflection, add volatile modifier to private static field

Tags: java, reflection, synchronization, volatile

It's possible to add the volatile modifier to a field that is private and static?

Example Code

```
// I don't know when test is initalized
public class Test {
    private static String secretString;

    public Test() {
        secretString = "random";
    }
}

public class ReflectionTest extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        Class<?> testClass = Class.forName("Test");
        Field testField = testClass.getDeclaredField("secretString");

        while (testField.get(null) == null) {
            // Sleep, i don't know when test is initalized
            // When it'is i need the String value
            // But this loop never end.
        }
    }
}
```

I think that if i set the field volatile the loop end
without any problem

Comment: add final keyword why you want volatile?

Comment: You mean, write `private static volatile String secretString`? Yes, that is possible. If you don't mean that, then your question is misleading and imprecise.

Comment: Instead of asking if it is possible, and whether it'll help, why don't you just try doing it and see what happens?

Comment: @Dima i don't know how to do

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes, i want that

Comment: So, write `private static volatile String secretString`. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I don't have access to the Test class

Comment: So again you have not clarified what you actually want. This is not a good way to have the community help you.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I want read the field secretString from another thread, but i can't because of synchronization, so i need to add volatile modifier to secretString, and then read, but i don't know how to do

Comment: The key thing, which I asked at the outset, was whether you do or don't want to write `private static volatile`. Your answer was "yes, I want that" instead of pointing out *which* of the two options you want. Your comment above once again does not specify that, although by now it has become semi-clear. You want to add the modifier via reflection at runtime. You can't, reflection is not an API which modifies classes.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik My question is: I have a class named Test, i don't know when and where it's initalized, i want to read a field of this class so i open another thread and i say in a loop when the field value isn't equals to null the test class is initalized and then i read the value of field, but the loop never end, so i think is a problem of synchronization for this reason i think that if i set field volatile this problem will solve, but i don't know how to set the volatile modifier in runtime for the field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have access to the class, you cannot modify it.

Instead, find the code that instantiates it, and add a synchronized block around it:

```
synchronized(Test.class) {
   new Test();
}
```

Now, in your thread code, do:

```
while(true) {
   synchronized(Test.class) {
       if(testField.get(null) == null) break;
   }
   // ... whatever 
}
```

May I ask why you need this? If a field is made private, there is usually a reason for it. You are circumventing the class creator's intent with your use of reflection ... 
Also, initializing static fields in an instance constructor seems ... fishy :-/

Comment: This don't solve my problem the field is always null

Comment: If the field is always null, then your loop will never exit :) This has nothing to do with threads or volatility. You need some code to modify the value of the field.

Comment: i need to read the value of field when the Test class is initalized

Comment: If the field is always null, then the class is not initialized.

Comment: i'm sure that the class is initalized

Comment: When class is initialized, the field is set to some non-null value, right? If so, then either the class  is never initialized or the field is not always null. If you are sure of the contrary, then you are obviously wrong. This is just simple logic, there is no place for an argument.

Comment: The class that declare the field is a singleton class i'm trying to get the instance, it's declared private static Test instance; in the constructor there is Test.instance = this; and a System.out, i see the System.out but my code always read null

Comment: And you are creating the instance within a synchronized block? And your test is done within a synchronized block? And you are synchronizing on the same thing in both cases? Then there must be something wrong with your aura, magically preventing your program from working. Show the complete code that demonstrates the problem. A complete source that can be compiled and run.

Comment: i don't construct the class, but i know that isn't synchronized

Comment: in that case, you are out of luck. If it is not synchronized, you won't see the changes made in another thread, until the cpu caches are flushed, which may never happen. I'll say it again: perhaps, it is declared as private for a reason. You are not supposed to be accessing that field.